# How to verify at compile time that method parameters are from a certain set

Tags: java

I have a method that takes a String parameter (upload), that can have only two values: true or false.  Is there a way to check that correct value is passed to this method at compile time?  I tried with enum but got as far as runtime check:

```
public static enum eTrueFalse {TRUE, FALSE};
...

public Result loadSDP(String sdpFile, String name, String upload){
    StringBuilder sbOptionalParameters = new StringBuilder();
    if (upload != null){
        if (isTrueFalse(upload)){
            sbOptionalParameters.append(" --upload ");
            sbOptionalParameters.append(upload);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The 'upload' parameter takes only 'true' or 'false' value.  Cannot handle: "
                    + upload);
        }
    }
    ...
}

private boolean isTrueFalse(String st) {
    for(eTrueFalse tf : eTrueFalse.values()){
        if(tf.name().equalsIgnoreCase(st)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This question applies to a method with a parameter that has more than 2 predefined values as well, of course.

I would like to have the check at compile time, because execution is very time consuming.  It would be great to have the check done early.  Any pointers appreciated.

**Edit:**
The above example was not a good one since it can be easily solved with boolean (or Boolean), while I was looking for a more generic solution.  Here is a (hopefully) better example.  I have an enum:

```
public enum MEDIA_TYPE {XML, JSON};
```

and a method that takes it:

```
public ClientResponse get(String address, String user,
        String password, MEDIA_TYPE mediaType) {
...
return webResource.queryParams(new 
        MultivaluedMapImpl()).accept(mediaType).get(ClientResponse.class);
```

}

The problem with the above is that accept method takes String, so I need to translate my enum to String.  What is the best approach?  Switch statement?  Adding a constructor and a getter to the enum class?  Other?

Answer (score 4):

If you want the check to happen at compile time, then you need to use the type system - specifically `boolean` for values that can only be `true` or `false`.

However if you have code calling this method which has a String field, any conversion to `boolean` only happens at runtime, so you can not verify that `Boolean.valueOf(str)` does not throw an exception at compile-time.

Comment: Using Boolean in this particular case will work (null is allowed), however, I was looking for a solution to a problem where String can have a set of predefined values (not just true or false).  It looks like there is no way to enforce that check at compile time.

Comment: If null is not allowed, you can use lower-case `boolean` there - be aware of the differences.

Comment: Right, got that, thanks.  Just to verify, there is no way to enforce certain values at compile time, if there are more of them than just true/false, is this correct?

Comment: @Lidia, you could use enums also.

Comment: Where can I find references on using enums in this context (for checking values that are passed to a method, at compile time)?

Answer (score 0):

If the upload variable takes only true or false, is practically a Boolean. Therefore it would be better to use Boolean as the parameter class, which would result in a compile-time type check of the parameter class.
When the parameter class remains a String, there is no way to enforce such a check at compile time, as the value of the string parameter is evaluated at runtime.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  Matt b suggested that this can be done with enums, but there is no follow up from him on this.  Would you have an idea if that's correct and how to do it?

Comment: You could use enums, but then the parameter type should be an enum. If you really really need the String typed parameter, you could pass an enum by calling the toString() method on it. This doesn't enforce the use of enums - you can still put in any string value if you like.

Comment: The parameter does not need to be a String, but if I have an enum, I need to be able to extract the String value from it.  I'm not sure how to do it.   I have `public enum MEDIA_TYPE {XML, JSON};`.  I need to call WebResource.accept method and it expects a String.  What is the best way to go from enum to String in this case?  Do I create a case or some other if/else statement and assign enum to String that way, or do I create a class for the enum and assign String values to the enum in the class?  What's the best approach?

Comment: Added better example to the problem description above.

Comment: Adding String properties to the enum would be a good approach